# In JS, how to export all other files from the directory inside the index file?

Tags: javascript

Given the following file tree:

```
app/_components/Icon
├── Check
│   └── index.tsx
├── Close
│   └── index.tsx
└── index.tsx
```

How to export all the `Icon/*` components as named exports from the _app/*components/Icon/index.ts* in the smallest amount of code, so I don't have to add a new import/export statements when adding a new `Icon/*`?

I'd like to later be able to `import { Check, Close } from "@/app/_components/Icon"`.

---

I assume this is doable with some clever use of dynamic imports (e.g. `require.context('./')`), but I wonder is there a syntax that allows this using only `import` and `export` with wildcards `*`.

Comment: JavaScript's module system doesn't have any kind of wildcard (or even any requirement of a file system a wildcard might apply to, just opaque string module specifiers), so it can't do this. But what bundler are you using? Bundlers sometimes add features that the standard mechanism doesn't have.

Comment: At the moment I use webpack, but I will eventually opt into Turbopack that's in beta right now for Next.js

Comment: FWIW, it's probably worth recasting the question slightly to ask if those can do it, since there's nothing in JavaScript itself that can. (I don't know anything about Turbopack, but if Webpack doesn't already have this feature, you could probably write a loader to do it.)